# Dropdown menu in table cell via CSS only

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal navigation bar that I am trying to make in to a dropdown menu by using a list and CSS to display the list when it is hovered over. Since this is in a table I am having issues with it not displaying properly. How do I fix the CSS so that this displays properly? Browser will be IE11 and Chrome.

**CSS:**

```
#coolMenu,
#coolMenu ul {
    list-style: none;
}

#coolMenu {
    float: left;
}
#coolMenu > li {
    float: left;
}
#coolMenu li a {
    display: block;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#coolMenu ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
}
#coolMenu ul li a {
    width: 80px;

}
#coolMenu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<td colspan="100%">
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
            <tr style="text-align:center; font-size:x-small; color-white;">
                <td>
                    <ul id="coolMenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Link1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">four</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">five</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <ul id="coolMenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Link2</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: What does "not displaying properly" mean? Oh...and tables for layout...really?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I note is that the `id` having `coolMenu` is repeated twice. **The `id`s should be unique!** Please correct that. And for your query, well, there's no full HTML, but still, put a `position: relative` and use of `position: absolute` will work out well.

Check out the following snippet, is this what you are looking:

```css
#coolMenu,
#coolMenu ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#coolMenu {
  float: left;
}
#coolMenu > li {
  float: left;
}
#coolMenu li a {
  display: block;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 0 1.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#coolMenu ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 999;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
}
#coolMenu ul li a {
  width: 80px;

}
#coolMenu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
  <tr style="text-align:center; font-size:x-small; color-white;">
    <td>
      <ul id="coolMenu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link1</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">four</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">five</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
      <ul id="coolMenu2">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```